# How to manage views (.html) in es6 common js

Tags: javascript, html, import, ecmascript-6

As we import js in ES6

ex: show below

```
import Ajax from "./Ajax.js";
let http = new Ajax();
```

I need same for importing .html

```
import home from "./Home.html";
```

Can anyone please provide me an example on the same... Thanks in advance

Comment: What exactly do you expect the value of `home` to be? What does it mean to import an HTML document into JavaScript? What do you plan to do with the value?

Comment: import is not a keyword for downloading stuffs dynamically! Just get the .html file with ajax or use any template engine.

Comment: @Felix Kling my task to include html file and template binding, i need it as MVC pattern in es6

Comment: @Sen Jacob i have done using ajax html request but that is not good idea, my raw code will be visible in console response at browser so i need clear approach

Comment: Depending on the context you either want to use wepback with its html-loader, or simply use the `fs` module (assuming this runs in Node). Neither of these have anything to do with ES6. ES6 itself doesn't provide any of the functionality you want.

Comment: @Felix Kling Any example on fs module how it works?

Comment: https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html

Comment: @Felix Kling thanks